# AdSense ads are not being displayed on my homepage

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

I have a relatively new site that has AdSense installed in the same location across each page. Ads however are not (and have never been) displaying on my homepage.

I have checked that I have enough content, that my image to text ratio is OK, I have no warnings or messages in my AdSense account, and the ads are displaying fine on all my other pages.

I have also ran the Google Debug URL string on my homepage which does display ads.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Is Google at least placing a blank ad? If so, then there are no ads to run on that page- I assume. Otherwise, there may be another problem that gets in the way.

Comment: How did you insert your AdSense code? I see your site runs WordPress. Are you using a plugin, or manually inserting the snippets of javascript?

Comment: Adsense ads are visible on the home page. In fact, there are five of them. At the moment, your adsense account is not revoked. But if you continue this way, it will be, shortly. And you cannot label adsense ads as "Sponsor message". There are clear guidelines in Adsense Programme policies on how to label adsense ads. This does not answer your question, but indicate that there was no real question to start with.

Comment: @JackLockyer As others have commented, the ads do appear so this question is being put on hold.

Comment: @RanaPrathap Thank you for your guidance, as you can see I have made the changes you suggested. There was however a 'real' question and I find your response slightly patronizing, this site is to help fellow webmasters, not to put-down those that make mistakes.

Comment: @Jack Lockyer sorry if I sounded patronizing. I am all open to helping webmasters. In fact I seek help more often than I provide help. And my comment was intended to make the asker know that his question of why adsense ads are not displayed does not exist because adsense ads are actually displayed. I might have sounded bad there, my apologies again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your ad's showing on your home page. I would do a Control R refresh or F5 to clear you cache. Check in a private browser or from another device.

Answer (score 2):

It could possibly be the amount of ads you are attempting to run means approval has been revoked.  I believe you are only allowed up to 3, but you are running 5.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295#Google_ad_limit_per_page

The blank iframes tend to be what appear when a page is in the awaiting approval phase.

Have you checked your adwords account for any warning messages?

Comment: You would still see ads just not more than the allowed amount per page